# Patterns for storing grid-like data in a database

Tags: database-design, spreadsheet

We are attempting to build something akin to a very basic version of a spreadsheet or a database table. We have rows and columns, and we want the user to be able to add rows or columns, and do some basic sorting/filtering.

One concept we've had was to simply create a new database table for every "document" that we want to store. This way, the SQL is simple and fast. However, this brings about a plethora of problems including managing the different tables per client, having to execute "ALTER TABLE" statements when they want to add a new column, and similar issues.

So, what is the best way to store grid-like data with unknown columns in a single (or multiple) tables in a database such that sorting and filtering doesn't become a nightmare?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you share more information about what you are trying to accomplish, this simple ER model might be a good place to start:

[image]

`ROW` and `COLUMN` are integer "coordinates" within the spreadsheet.

Pros:

- Simple.
- Potentially very efficient for "sorting" and "filtering".
- Efficient (storage-wise) for "sparse" data - i.e. where there are big "holes" in the spreadsheet.

Cons:

- Inefficient (storage-wise) for "dense" data, since a lot of repetition will happen in the CELL's PK.

  - Depending on your DBMS, you might be able to minimize the space overhead using *compressed indexes*.
  - You could even use *compressed clustered table* ([key-compressed index-organized table](http://isu.ifmo.ru/docs/doc112/server.112/e10595/tables012.htm#sthref2318) in Oracle parlance), with the unfortunate consequence of being able to access the calls efficiently **only** row-wise or column-wise but not both, and a limited ability to filter by `VALUE` (secondary indexes are expensive in a clustered table).
- You have to choose the type of the `VALUE` in advance, making it awkward to store values of non-uniform types. There are ways to work around this, but they add complexity and can potentially be a performance concern.

Comment: +1 & Accepted - Thanks very much! I wound up using a slight alteration of this pattern which separates the CellColumns into their own table so that I can store some additional data about them (such as title, type of data, etc). I appreciate the help!